# Getting "SCRIPT70: Permission denied" only with EDGE Browser / JAVASCRIPT ERROR

Tags: javascript, flash, microsoft-edge

I have an EDGE Browser problem:

after a long research I did find the reason, but not a solution.

When using javascript "window.location.href='to_my_url.php' and I have a flash inside my current page, I will receive SCRIPT70 errors access denied:

[Screenshot from Console in EDGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpifO.png)

When removing the flash part this problem does not occur ....

You can check it yourself on http://dev.gruppenhaus.de/index2.html when you click on the orange button "Go to EDGE SCRIPT70 ERRORS".

Thanks for your help
Regards
Chris

Comment: I don't use edge at all to test that behavior (I disabled it some minutes after upgrading to win10, I advice you to do also for [privacy issues](https://www.privacytools.io/)), but I tried it in IE11 and it's working fine. I see after some researchs that's a security problem and usually fired by, for example, an iframe which is trying to load some js files from a different domain (or sub-domain) ... so are you using an iframe ?

Comment: Yes. There is an IFRAME inside. But for testing reasons I removed it (without any change). What works is: removing the FLASH inside. Then there are not SCIPRT70 errors ...

Comment: May be your SWF is trying to load those blocked files or something like that ...

Comment: Maybe, but when calling another page with "window.location.href" there is nothing happen .... but on the new loaded website the errors occur (and nothing happens from the flash ...)(.... this is a mystery for me ....

Comment: This issue appears to occur when a iframe references an object outside the frame and then the iframe is removed from the DOM and the 
object is referenced again.  This hits a permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the latest stable release of **Edge 14.14393**

More information can be found in this ticket:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8443109/

This conversation was about the 'iframe' issue, however there was a response saying the following: "We are showing this as fixed in our latest builds (14393+). Looking forward to more feedback from you in the future."

This doesn't necessarily mean that it was just the iframe issue, it could be more than that since this ticket was made after the issue was known and fixed.